# Jquery: mousedown effect (while left click is held down)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, click

I need a function that executes a function while a button is pressed and stops executing when the button is let go

```
$('#button').--while being held down--(function() {
     //execute continuously
});
```

Comment: Take a look at my question, which is based on this one. There is an improvement to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316638/jquery-mousdown-with-setinterval-endless

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I believe something like this would work:

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');

clicker.mousedown(function(){
    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        // Do something continuously 
    }, 500);

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

**See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8FmRd/**

Comment: One problem - if you let go off of the hit area, the effect loops forever. You should probably look at having the `mouseup` function on the entire document, rather than just `clicker`.

Comment: Or instead of the setInterval solution he might want to use the mousemove event.

Comment: @baz Hmmm.. Unlikely, as *any* sort of mouse movement after the button is held would call `clearTimeout`, which generally speaking doesn't seem like the correct behavior here.

Comment: @yi There would be no timeout. On mousedown a class would be added to the element, and on mousemove the function would be executed (based on the class). Global mouseup would remove the class. I was thinking he is trying to do some kind of dragging.

Comment: @YiJiang: FYI -- The demo is hitting a 404 now.

Answer (score 19):

A small modification to the original answer:

```
$('#Clicker').mousedown(function () {
    //do something here
    timeout = setInterval(function () {
        //do same thing here again
    }, 500);

    return false;
});
$('#Clicker').mouseup(function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
$('#Clicker').mouseout(function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

With the mouseout event on the Clicker it stops when you move your mouse out of the click area.

The reason why I suggest to do the same thing twice is to get a smoother effect. If you don't do it once before the timeout is set it will be a delay of, in this case, 500ms before something happens.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure JavaScript implementation of the supplied solutions which has extended support for touch screens. You supply the `id`, `action` to perform (`function(){}`) and the `interval` (ms) to repeat the `action`. Note that this implementation will also execute the `action` immediately, rather than waiting for the `interval` to lapse.

```
// Configures an element to execute a function periodically whilst it holds the user's attention via a mouse press and hold.
function assertPeriodicPress(id, action, interval) {
  // Listen for the MouseDown event.
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('mousedown', function(ev) { action(); timeout = setInterval(action, interval); return false; }, false);
  // Listen for mouse up events.
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('mouseup', function(ev) { clearInterval(timeout); return false; }, false);
  // Listen out for touch end events.
  document.getElementById(id).addEventListener('touchend', function(ev) { clearInterval(timeout); return false; }, false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.click2=function(cb,interval){
   var timeout;
   if(!interval) interval=100;
   $(this).mousedown(function () { 
      var target=this;
       timeout = setInterval(function(){
          cb.apply(target);
       }, interval);

    return false;
   }).mouseup(function () {
      clearInterval(timeout);
      return false;
   }).mouseout(function () {
      clearInterval(timeout);
      return false;
   });
}
```