# Image slider not sliding after clicking the right arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

This problem seems quite strange , I checked for replacement for my code but all of them give the same problem . One replacement can be [Jquery: mousedown effect (while left click is held down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down) .
I am trying to make a slider that will slide the thumbs of images to right or left . From the thumbs the person can then choose and click the image he wants and it will get displayed .The thumbs can slide to both right and left .
The problem is that after clicking the right button the images don't slide again towards left , I think it is something with clearinterval .
Here is the fiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/18/
After clicking the right arrow the left sliding effect wont work .

```
$("#popUpInnerArrowLeft").mousedown(function(event) {
           movetoleft();
});

var into ,into2 ;

function movetoleft() {
    function moveit() { 
     $(".thumbsInnerContainer").animate({right:'+=10px'});
     }

    into = setInterval(function() {     moveit();   }, 500); 

}

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    clearInterval(into);

});



//for the right arrow

$("#popUpInnerArrowRight").mousedown(function(event) {
           movetoright();
});

function movetoright() {

    function moveit2() {    
     $(".thumbsInnerContainer").animate({left:'+=10px'});
     }

    into2 = setInterval(function() {    moveit2();  }, 500); 

}

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    clearInterval(into2);
});
```

Comment: can you please set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to try this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/18/ @OptimusPrime

Comment: For me it slides to left as well as right, with a change, what else you have a problem with?

Comment: After pressing the right arrow it wont slide to left .

Comment: check fiddle in my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it works for me, http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/19/

And I only changed,

```
    $(".thumbsInnerContainer").animate({
        right: '+=10px'
    });
```

to

```
    $(".thumbsInnerContainer").animate({
        left: '+=10px'
    });
```

Comment: I never thought , this can make a difference .Thanks .

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/arXnZ/

The issue is with the use of $(document).mouseup()

You should be doing something like :

```
$('#popUpInnerArrowRight, #popUpInnerArrowLeft ').mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(stillDown);
});
```

Check the fiddle for a full example of how to do this.