# How to add MouseDown event to a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button which is like below and a jQuery which increase the size of the slider perfectly:

```
<button id='plus' type="button">+</button>

$('#plus').click(function() {
     s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
 });
```

But I would like to change the size up as long as the mouse is down over the button. I tried this but it didn't do the job! (it is actually acting like click event).

```
$('#plus').mousedown(function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
});
```

How can I do this in jQuery?

Comment: Your code seems ok, can you move your entire page to jsFiddle and add the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just understood that you want something to **continuously happen while the button is pressed** down.

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down),

the main idea is to start an interval when button is down, which will do the update on every round, and when the button is released, this interval will stop.

for example:

```
var timeout, clicker = $('#plus');

clicker.mousedown(function(){
    timeout = setInterval(function(){
        // Do something continuously 
        s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" );
    }, 500);

    return false;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(timeout);
    return false;
});
```

hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Gal V but same thing happening

Comment: @MonaCoder iv'e edited my answer, now i understand you better.

Comment: Thanks Gal this is working now! sorry I need 6 more mins to accept your reply as a correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#plus').bind('mousedown', function() { s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );
});
```

OR

```
$('#plus').on('mousedown', function() { s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as `bind` is deprecated using `on` should be the better solution:

```
$('#plus').on('mousedown', function() {
    s.slider('value', s.slider('value') + s.slider( "option", "step" ) );   
});
```