# How to create hours and minutes spinner using requestAnimationFrame()?

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

**Desired Behaviour**

Create two "spinners" for hour and minute definition using `requestAnimationFrame()`.

**Current Behaviour**

I've adapted [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127763) to incorporate two "spinner" instances.

The `hours` spinner is working, however clicking on the arrow buttons to in/decrement the `minutes` value is changing the `hours` value, instead of the `minutes` value.

**What I've Tried**

What I've tried feels a bit repetitive, as I've tried to call `requestAnimationFrame()` twice, but I can't think of a more dynamic way to execute it.

**jsFiddle**

[jsFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/xpd02o7a/)

```js
//adapted from:
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/28127763

// the hrs 'input' area
var $hrs_input=$('.hrs_input > span');

// the mins 'input' area
var $mins_input=$('.mins_input > span');

// common variables
// the starting hr and mins value
var number=0;
// isDown starting value
var isDown=0;
// delay in changing value
var delay=200;
// ??
var nextTime=0;

requestAnimationFrame(watcher);
requestAnimationFrame(watcher2); // eek?

// ======= BEGIN for hours handling

$(".hr_arrow").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$(".hr_arrow").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$(".hr_arrow").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});

function handleMouseDown(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
if (e.target.id=='add_hr') {
isDown=1;
}
else if (e.target.id!='add_hr')  {
isDown=-1;
}
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
isDown=0;
}

function watcher(time) {

requestAnimationFrame(watcher);

if (time < nextTime) { 
return;
}

nextTime = time + delay;

// when adding
if (isDown === 1) {
// no conditional needed
number+=isDown;
$hrs_input.text(number);
}
// when subtracting
else if (isDown === -1) {
// conditional needed - only subtract if number is not 0
if (number !=0) {
number+=isDown;
$hrs_input.text(number);
}
}
}

// ======= END for hours handling


// ======= BEGIN for mins handling 
// just repeats the above hrs handling, with different 
// function names and div references

$(".min_arrow").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown2(e);});
$(".min_arrow").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp2(e);});
$(".min_arrow").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp2(e);});

function handleMouseDown2(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
if (e.target.id=='add_min') {
isDown=1;
}
else if (e.target.id!='add_min')  {
isDown=-1;
}
}

function handleMouseUp2(e){
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
isDown=0;
}

function watcher2(time) {

requestAnimationFrame(watcher2);

if (time < nextTime) { 
return;
}

nextTime = time + delay;

// when adding
if (isDown === 1) {
// no conditional needed
number+=isDown;
$mins_input.text(number);
}
// when subtracting
else if (isDown === -1) {
// conditional needed - only subtract if number is not 0
if (number !=0) {
number+=isDown;
$mins_input.text(number);
}
}
}

// ======= END for mins handling
```

```css
.hrs_input, .mins_input {
  background: #9be672 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  margin: 0 0 0 2px;
  min-width: 62px;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.hr_arrow, .min_arrow {
  background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.hr_arrow:hover, .min_arrow:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}

p {
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Click the up and down arrows to in/decrease the hours.</p>
<p>Desired Behaviour:  For minutes in/decrementing to work the same way.</p>
<!-- BEGIN hrs -->
<span class="hrs_input">hrs:  <span>&nbsp;</span>
</span>
<span id="add_hr" class="hr_arrow">&#x25B2;</span>
<span class="hr_arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
<!-- END hrs -->
<!-- BEGIN mins -->
<span class="mins_input">mins:  <span>&nbsp;</span>
</span>
<span id="add_min" class="min_arrow">&#x25B2;</span>
<span class="min_arrow">&#x25BC;</span>
<!-- END mins -->
```

**Code**

It's a fairly bulky chunk of code, but I'm thinking the problem may arise from calling `requestAnimationFrame()` twice, ie:

```
requestAnimationFrame(watcher);
requestAnimationFrame(watcher2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass the `if (time < nextTime)` in the second watcher, because the first watcher always increases the `nextTime` value before.

This happens because both watchers share the same global `time` and `nextTime` variables (this probably applies to `number` and `isDown` too).

Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kky0bdkx/

It has different global variables for each watcher, in order to avoid conflicts. This is one of the issues when working with globals. A better solution will probably be to figure out a way of rewriting the watchers with scoped variables.