# JQuery mousdown with setInterval endless

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mouse, mousedown

My question is referring onto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down) question.

At the moment I am using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8615582/1754625), but I still can trick that code, so the `clearInterval` won't stop. While holding my left mouse button I simple press the right one to open the contextmenu. Now the `clearInterval` wasn't called.

If I add the `contextmenu` event to the `clicker`, with a `clearInterval` it does get called, but it won't clear the interval.

**[See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/os2L94yq/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `clearInterval()` to the `mousedown` event:

```
clicker.mousedown(function() {
  clearInterval(timeout);
  timeout = setInterval(function() {
    clicker.text(count++);
  }, 500);

  return false;
});
```

That will be triggered on the context menu, and it will prevent multiple timers from running at once.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqbpqf06/)

Comment: Crap, that's a distinctly better solution than popped into my head. But I'll leave the important bit of my answer here: Setting a `setInterval` to a var only saves an identifying record, not the interval itself.

Comment: I thought your answer was fine and was surprised to see it deleted.  Good point re "Setting a `setInterval` ..."

Comment: I already tried to write a comment @DBS answer, because I was still able to "cheat" with fast clicks. I think this was caused through the fact of multiple access on one variable.
At the moment I'm not able to "cheat" on yours (@RickHitchcock) ;)