# hold down button after 1 second and loop the action using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

I got this code from:  [Jquery: mousedown effect (while left click is held down)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down)
It is behaving that if I am holding the button in every 50ms it will do something.

```
var timeout = 0;
$('#button_add').mousedown(function () {
    timeout = setInterval(function () {
        value_of_something ++;
    }, 50);
    return false;
    });
});
```

But what I want is to execute this part after holding down the button by 1 second and it will continuously do the action 50ms.

Comment: you need to use `setTimeout(function(){// code here } , 1000);`

Comment: After 1 sec I want to execute that code continuously in 50ms, but not after every 1 sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said you need to use `setTimeout()`

```
var timeout = 0;
$('#button_add').mousedown(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
      timeout = setInterval(function () {
                   value_of_something ++;
                }, 50);         
    } , 1000);
    return false;
});
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/8FmRd/1032/)

Comment: can you add how I will stop it? I can`t stop it with `mouseup and mouseout function`

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code... You have to clearTimeout when user mouseup :

```html
var timeout = 0;

$('#button_add').mousedown(function() {
    oneSecondTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = setInterval(function() {
            value_of_something++;
        }, 50);
    }, 1000);

    return false;
});

$("#button_add").mouseup(function() {
    clearTimeout(oneSecondTimer);
});
```