# jQuery mouse event on holding down left click

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseevent

Is there a jQuery event that fires only while holding down left mouse botton ?

I have tried the .mousedown() event but it doesn't seems to work for me.

Comment: I think that this answer your question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977091/jquery-mousedown-effect-while-left-click-is-held-down)

Comment: As per [mre] please show what you have tried and provide a more detailed  explanation of what you are trying to accomplish and what the code does differently from expectations. See also [ask]

Answer (score 1):

The button value in available in the mouse event. The buttons are numbered from the primary button at value 0 and upward.
Look at this example.

```js
const div = document.getElementById('log');
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    div.innerHTML+= ' '+e.button;
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  min-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="log"></div>
```

Comment: Ok, this seems to work better. I appreciate your help !!!